# why Search Schema inside a site collection will be showing properties from other site collections

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, site-collection, configuration

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013. and i have one web application and 6 site collections. now i went to a site collection , which is of type "Enterprise Wiki" , then i navigate to "Site Setting" >> "Site Collection Administration" >> "Search Schema". as follow:-

[image]

but i found that the search schema page is showing properties from other site collections ,, so can anyone adivce , why site collection search schema will be showing all the properties insde the web application and not just the properties realted to the current site site collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is when they were created, they were added on the SSA (Search Service Application) level not on the site collection level. I found this [article](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/creating-managed-properties-in-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/) very helpful in explaining the differences and limitations